# Injection Attacks against .NET DataView RowFilter

Tags: c#, encoding, sql-injection, dataview, rowfilter

So I'm writing a handler that filters a cached DataTable based on the AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath using the DataView RowFilter property.  What's the best way to encode the input to prevent an injection attack?

Is the following sufficient?  Is there a better/more-elegant way?

```
dataView.RowFilter = String.Format("Name LIKE '{0}%'", EncodeString(query));

private string EncodeString(string s)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = s[i];
        if (c == '*' || c == '%' || c == '[' || c == ']')
            sb.Append("[").Append(c).Append("]");
        else if (c == '\'')
            sb.Append("''");
        else
            sb.Append(c);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: i don't think you can inject sql here...only cause an exception. But, yes that is pretty much exactly what I do.

Comment: If you're using in-memory data, why use `DataTable` and not just any collection? You'd be able to filter it with `Where` and just not bother about injections.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev - I asked the question in '09 so it was probably a .NET 1.1 app.  Enterprises are slow to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inject sql in a RowFilter.

Edit: As pointed out, it is possible to get all rows in the table by injection, could something like the following work:

```
dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<string>("StringColumn").Contains(userInput))
    .ToList().ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r.Field<string>("StringColumn")));
```

Comment: RowFilter is a string very similar to a SQL Where clause and it is exploitable via injection if you are constructing the filter string from user input.  In my example I am filtering a DataTable based on the the URL (e.g http://site/handler/stringUsedInFilter) and the filter is a LIKE comparison thus anything after "handler/" needs to be sanitized otherwise something like "%25%25%25%25%25" would bypass minimum length and empty string checks to return the entire table contents.  "'" would cause the filter to be invalid and throw an exception. etc...

Comment: Yes in order to not return the full table you would have to guard. Is there ever a case where the entire table is returned or is that something you can guard against?

Comment: @Yuriy : What if the input they're looking to filter on really is %%%%%?  That wouldn't do them much good.  What if the input is O'Brien? That would cause an SyntaxErrorException to be thrown.  The input needs to be filtered.

Comment: Time to create a parameterized control inheriting from DataView?